# How to hide column in column picker

Tags: serenity-platform

I have a hidden column in Grid but I also wish to hide it in column picker. I need to keep that column in XYZColumns.cs file because I am using it as a quick filter

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attribute `[FilterOnly()]`.

For example:

```cs
[EditLink, Width(300), FilterOnly()]
public String Nombrecli { get; set; }
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I also had to add "QuickFilter" because the filter wasn't visible